# Azure storage blobs are not indexed within Google

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there a way to force Google to index Azure storage blobs? I have tried adding the URL using Google webmaster tools, but not luck.

I already know 'Azure Search' feature and that is not the one I'm looking for. I would expcet the blob files to appear in Google search results just like other files, as there are no restrictions set by robots.txt